# Left Join Multiple Tables and Avoid Duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle10g, left-join

I have two tables with a 1:n relationship to my base table, both of which I want to LEFT JOIN.

```
-------------------------------
Table A    Table B    Table C
-------------------------------
|ID|DATA|  |ID|DATA|  |ID|DATA|
-------------------------------
 1  A1      1  B1      1  C1
 -          -          1  C2
```

I'm using:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA a
    LEFT JOIN TableB b
           ON a.Id = b.Id
    LEFT JOIN TableC c
           ON a.Id = c.Id
```

But this is showing duplicates for TableB:

```
1  A1    B1   C1
1  A1    B1   C2
```

How can I write this join to ignore the duplicates? Such as:

```
1  A1    B1     C1
1  A1    null   C2
```

Comment: The join is working as it is supposed to work.  Can you explain what you want your results to look like?  Why do you want NULL in the second column, when there is a matching value?

Comment: I'm OK with dups on my left table, but I want the occurences of the right tables to stay true to the relationship. So, since there is only one row for ID `1` on `TableB`, I only want to see it in my result set once.

Comment: Value A1 from tableA can NOT join with value C2 from tableC because they have different IDs.

Comment: Sorry, the ID were supposed to be the same.

Comment: In edited scenario: why do you want to null tableB "duplicates" and NOT tableA "duplicates"? Generally in multiple joins that is what you get, you can present/output it differently later.

Comment: @Paul . . . Can you explain why you want this?  Although you can do it (see my answer), I suspect you want something a bit different.

Comment: @Gordon ... In the end, I'm building C# objects off this data, one per row in TableA. I will build attributes of this object off of TableB and TableC, so I don't want extra data in my results while I'm iterating over the results.

Comment: Post your tables schemas so we can better understand

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do logic to get what you want.  You want for any multiple b.ids to eliminate them.  You can identify them using `row_number()` and then use `case` logic to make subsequent values NULL:

```
select a.id, a.val,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by b.id, b.seqnum order by b.id) = 1 then val
        end) as bval
       c.val as cval
from TableA a left join
     (select b.*, row_number() over (partition by b.id order by b.id) as seqnum
      from tableB b
     ) b
     on a.id = b.id left join
     tableC c
     on a.id = c.id
```

I don't think you want a full join between B and C, because you will get multiple rows.  If B has 2 rows for an id and C has 3, then you will get 6.  I suspect that you just want 3.  To achieve this, you want to do something like:

```
select *
from (select b.*, row_number() over (partition by b.id order by b.id) as seqnum
      from TableB b
     ) b
     on a.id = b.id full outer join
     (select c.*, row_number() over (partition by c.id order by c.id) as seqnum
      from TableC c
     ) c
     on b.id = c.id and
        b.seqnum = c.seqnum join
     TableA a
     on a.id = b.id and a.id = c.id
```

This is enumerating the "B" and "C" lists, and then joining them by position on the list.  It uses a full outer join to get the full length of the longer list.

The last join references both tables so TableA can be used as a filter.  Extra ids in B and C won't appear in the results.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use distinct

```
SELECT distinct * FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b
       ON a.Id = b.Id
LEFT JOIN TableC c
       ON a.Id = c.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it as a UNION, i.e.

```
 SELECT TableA.ID, TableB.ID, TableC.Id
   FROM TableA a
         INNER JOIN TableB b ON a.Id = b.Id
         LEFT JOIN TableC c ON a.Id = c.Id
 UNION
 SELECT TableA.ID, Null, TableC.Id
   FROM TableA a
         LEFT JOIN TableC c ON a.Id = c.Id
```

i.e. one SELECT to being back the first row and another to bring back the second row. It's a bit rough because I don't know anything about the data you are trying to read but the principle is sound. You may need to rework it a bit.